# Should I have another system in addition to Etag to handle Concurrency?

Tags: http, jpa, concurrency, http-headers, etag

I've just discovered that Etags may help me to handle concurrent updates on one resource.
But it seems to me that Etags only are not enough to handle concurrency.
Perhaps I am wrong, therefore I would like to ask for your advice.

Below is a use case:

- Let O be an object such as O.text = «Hello»
- Let A and B be two users
- A wants to modify O such as O.text = «Hello A»
- B wants to modify O   such as O.text = «Hello B»

A user should be allowed to persist object modifications **if and only
if the state of the object has not been modified by another changed
since the reading of the object state**.

Below is a scenario where concurrency is only handled through Etags:

1. Update Request from user with Etag = [hash_O]
2. Read object O from database
3. Create Etag for object O. Result is [hash_O]
4. Compare Etags (the one from the user's request and the one created
   after database read)
5. Etags are equal
6. Update O in database

In my opinion, users **A and B can arrive at the same time at step 5)**.
So it is possible A updates O.name with "Hello A" and just after  B updates O.name with "Hello B" despite state of O has just changed.

**Do you agree that this scenario is possible?**

If so, it seems to me that step 6) :

- should be a copy of all the steps from 2) to 5) + the update in database
- but this time, all actions should be performed within an atomic instruction

  - i.e: by using synchronized methods in JAVA

So to summarize, I should first check Etags and if test is successful then check Etag and perform update in database in an atomic way.

- **Do you agree with my analysis?**
- **Or are there any misunderstandings from me?**

So maybe the use of annotation @version from JPA could also be used in addition of ETags.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your analysis is essentially correct.

To satisfy the `If-Match` ETag semantics on update you have to avoid the kind of race condition you describe. Now, whether there is a race condition at all and how you avoid it is going to depend on the implementation. Nothing about the definition of ETags requires that resources are objects, that they persist in the database, that ETags are hashes, etc.

For some architectures you might be able to do the update with an atomic database command. For others you might need a database transaction at a certain isolation level. For others you might need some kind of lock or code-level synchronization primitive.

I don't know enough about JPA or your specific architecture to give concrete advice, but yes, you're right that this is a problem you have to think about and take steps to avoid.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It is reassuring to see that I'm not on the wonrg path. :) About the JPA @version annotation, actually it just means that you have to insert a "version" column in your table. Then if "UPDATE … WHERE  current_version = etag_value" returns 0 updated rows then it means that the value has already been updated yb someone else.

Comment: @Kris: Got it. Yes, that approach is exactly what I was thinking of when I mentioned *an atomic database command*, and it should solve the problem.